# Selenium, get css value from xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hello is it possible to get value "After market close" by using XPath locator strategy?

```
<span class="marketClosed genToolTip oneliner reverseToolTip" data-tooltip="After market close"></span>
```

my goal is to get all data ordered by index if is "Before market open" or "After market close" or none. All XPath are the same except the index number.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code and explanation below:

```
# Locate the desired element first
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.marketClosed.genToolTip.oneliner.reverseToolTip")

# use ".get_attribute" method as below to get the value stored in attribute "data-tooltip"
print(element.get_attribute("data-tooltip"))
```

Output:

```
After market close
```